# Binding a List of Objects to a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a list of objects and I'm trying to bind it to a TreeView in WPF:

```
private List<SlideIssue> slideIssuesList = new List<SlideIssue>();
```

Here the XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <TreeView x:Name="mainTreeView" BorderThickness="0">

    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And the binding attempt:

```
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
item.HeaderTemplate = headerTemplate;

foreach (var issue in slideIssuesList)
{
    if (slideNumber == issue.SlideNumber)
    {                                            
        TreeViewItem child = new TreeViewItem();

        child.ItemsSource = slideIssuesList;

        child.HeaderTemplate = itemTemplate;
        item.Items.Add(child);
    }
}
item.IsExpanded = true; 
mainTreeView.Items.Add(item);
```

At runtime, this is what I get:

[image: Here is the picture]

I want to access the particular Properties of the "SlideIssue" Object. How do I do that?

Comment: Check if SideIssue has public properties. only public properties are displayed in treeview

Comment: they are all public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `DataTemplate` for your `SlideIssue` type and bind any element in the template to any of the class' `public` properties:

```
<TreeView x:Name="mainTreeView" BorderThickness="0"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SlideIssue}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SlideNumber}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeOtherPropertyOfSlideIssue}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Change "WpfApplication1" to the name of `namespace` in which the `SlideIssue` class is defined.

> It kinda works. But I've build a complicated template in C# so i prefer creating it from there. I only have one problem: can you help me write this line of code to C#?

The easiest and preferred way to create a `DataTemplate` programmatically is to use the `XamlReader.Parse` method:

```
DataTemplate dataTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" xmlns:local=\"clr-namespace:WpfApplication1;assembly=WpfApplication1\" DataType=\"{x:Type local:SlideIssue}\"><StackPanel><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding SlideNumber}\" /><TextBlock Text=\"{Binding SomeOtherPropertyOfSlideIssue}\" /></StackPanel></DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;
```

Just remember to replace "WpfApplication1" with the actual name of the namespace and assembly in which your `SlideIssue` class is defined.

Comment: It kinda works. But I've build a complicated template in C# so i prefer creating it from there. I only have one problem: can you help me write this line of code to C#? <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SlideIssue}"> Thanks!

Comment: The easiest and preferred way to create a `DataTemplate` programmatically is to use the `XamlReader.Parse` method. Please refer to my edited answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override ToString() method in the SlideIssue class.
When you bind any object to control it call ToString() method to print data, if ToString() isn't overrided it print reference class name.